# is it possible to create process pool in golang

Tags: go, process-pool

we have a async task scheduler system, which use golang's exec.Command to execute php scripts. Each time, the scheduler fetch a task from message queue, it will create a new exec.Command to execute the task.

Sometimes, there are almost thousands of tasks need to be executed at once. In this case, the scheduler will create thousands of exec.Command, then destroy them after a while.

I wanna know if there is a way to create a process pool(or something like this) so that we can reuse the exec.Command to reduce the cost of create new child process.

ps: I noticed that exec.Command can't be reused after called run.

**UPATE** 
the current logic would like below:

```
 func nsqMessageHandler(msg *nsq.Message) error{

      var task Task
      err:= json.Unmarshal(msg.Body,&task)
      ....
      cmd:=exec.Command("php",task.Payload...)
      err:=cmd.Start()
      ....
      err= cmd.Run()
      err=cmd.Process.Kill()
      ...
 }
```

Comment: You did not ask a question actually. It is possible to run commands using with `exec.Command`. It is possible to interact with those using stdin/stdout and other mechanisms OS'es provide.

Comment: Please post what you have tried in go.

Comment: @zerkms already updated

Comment: Reality check: wouldn't it be simpler to set up a stock `php-fpm` server and shovel tasks to it (via a "front-end" web-server or directly—something [like this](https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/using-php-fpm-as-a-simple-built-in-async-queue)? I mean, `php-fpm` implements intricate logic around managing PHP processes and is available for any sensible server-side OS (from personal experience, I may say that on Debian it also has sensible configuration defaults).

Comment: @kostix  well, we are transferring from php to golang.

Comment: To my knowledge it is not possible to re-use a PHP process (with the cli sapi). It executes one script (or command) and then exits. Use php-fpm for that, as suggested by kostix.

Comment: This depends way more on the PHP than the Go code. If the PHP script executes a task and returns, then obviously it cannot be "reused" in any meaningful way. If it continues running and accepting tasks, then yes of course; just keep submitting tasks to it.

Comment: @Adrian I totally agree with you and kositx's suggestion. But  the php script has to be executed in cli mode so that we choose the exec.Command. I was trying to find a way to create a child process pool(like thread pool), so when a new task comes, the scheduler can reuse the process to execute the script. Any idea ?

Comment: My comment stands... If the script exits after finishing a task, then there is nothing to reuse.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely **yes**. You can create a **blocking** channel which you submit the jobs to. Then you can create a set of "workers" by spawning **goroutines** that take the job<-channel as input and have for example an output channel to publish progress or results. The workers now just read on the channel and once one of it gets a job it will be working.

You want to prevent the workers from shutting down right at the beginning, so you need some method of blocking them. One way to solve this problem is to use a `waitgroup` and let the workers decrease the `waitgroup` index by one if one of them is off. Furthermore you want to stop the workers but you cannot stop a goroutine from outside - so you have to implement a job which you can pass to a worker which forces them to stop by their own.

An example from [gobyexample.com](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools)

```
// In this example we'll look at how to implement
// a _worker pool_ using goroutines and channels.

package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

// Here's the worker, of which we'll run several
// concurrent instances. These workers will receive
// work on the `jobs` channel and send the corresponding
// results on `results`. We'll sleep a second per job to
// simulate an expensive task.
func worker(id int, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- int) {
    for j := range jobs {
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "started  job", j)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println("worker", id, "finished job", j)
        results <- j * 2
    }
}

func main() {

    // In order to use our pool of workers we need to send
    // them work and collect their results. We make 2
    // channels for this.
    jobs := make(chan int, 100)
    results := make(chan int, 100)

    // This starts up 3 workers, initially blocked
    // because there are no jobs yet.
    for w := 1; w <= 3; w++ {
        go worker(w, jobs, results)
    }

    // Here we send 5 `jobs` and then `close` that
    // channel to indicate that's all the work we have.
    for j := 1; j <= 5; j++ {
        jobs <- j
    }
    close(jobs)

    // Finally we collect all the results of the work.
    for a := 1; a <= 5; a++ {
        <-results
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not what I want